# How to prepare for the Prince2 Practitioner exam

Tags: prince2

I've just passed by Prince2 foundation exam (through online material), and I've scheduled my practitioner exam in 2 weeks. My understanding is that the practitioner exam doesn't cover any new material, but is just more in depth.

How should I prepare for such an exam? Should I keep trying to memorize definitions etc? Or should I be trying to apply Prince2 in my organisation to get more a feeling of it?

Comment: please read my question also
https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/23682/prince2-practitioner-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No new ground but very different style of questions. They are still multiple choice, but include types like "assertion-justification" that I had never seen before. The other catch is that the questions are based on a scenario that you are provided with, so they are all to some degree inter-related.

Your best bet is to track down practice exams online and try them out. The body that regulates the PRINCE2 exams has an example at [this link](http://www.apmg-exams.com/index.aspx?subid=9&masterid=4). Once you are comfortable with them and consistently scoring reasonably well on a consistent basis you may as well give the real exam a shot.